# Table in ReactJS appearing twice

Tags: reactjs, html-table, datatable, react-table

[image]

I am trying to create a table in ReactJS and enter rows in it using API data. The columns are fixed. But somehow, two tables are appearing and data is getting divided in both of them.

```
<React.Fragment>
    {error ? <p>{error.message}</p> : null}
    {!isLoading ? (
      users.map(user => {
        const { name, owner } = user;
        return (
          <table class="table table-bordered table-secondary" id="tableBorder">
        <thead style={{backgroundColor:"#3787d8",color:"white"}}>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <td>{FullName}</td>          
        </table>
        );
      })
    ) : (
      <h3>Loading...</h3>
    )}
  </React.Fragment>
```

{FullName} gives two names which is showing one in each table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two tables are appearing because you're rendering the entire table in the map function. Try just rendering the rows/columns that need to be produced per the data:

```
              <React.Fragment>
                {error ? <p>{error.message}</p> : null}
                {!isLoading ? (
                <table class="table table-bordered table-secondary" id="tableBorder">
                <thead style={{backgroundColor:"#3787d8",color:"white"}}>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                {
                    users.map(user => {
                    const { name, owner } = user;
                    return (
                        <td>{FullName}</td>  
                    );
                    })
                }
                </table>
            ) : (
              <h3>Loading...</h3>
            )}
            </React.Fragment>
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. My above code is already inside the render method. Please bear with me, I am absolutely new on React :)

Comment: Okay I see. You can just remove the `<table>` tags from the map function then. I'll update my answer.

Comment: That should be what you're looking for. Although I'm not sure where the `FullName` variable is coming from... The idea is to map through `users`, and only produce a new **row** for each item. Not a new **table** for each item. With your current code, if there were 10 items in the users array, you'd end up with 10 tables. Make sense?

Comment: Fixed. Working Fine. Thanks a ton! :)

Comment: Sorry about the syntax error, easy to get lost in brackets without an editor!

Comment: If the above FullName has multiple data, is there a way to print them in seperate rows under the Name column?

Comment: If that were the case, why not use `FullName.map` rather than `user.map`?? Either way, I'm probably misunderstanding your question. Consider what you're asking thoroughly, and perhaps create a separate post if you can't figure it out yourself upon fleshing it out. Prolonged discussions are frowned upon in the comments section :)